# Select em 3 tabelas retornando vários OIDs

Tags: sql-server, select, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-select, tabela-html

Script só funciona retornando um único codpro (4609), precisava que ele retornasse vários

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT a.filial, a.codpro, b.descricaolonga , a.quant, a.estminimo, c.filial AS 'filial ped', c.quant AS 'carteira', c.quantrec AS 'recebido'
FROM ITEMFILEST a, COMPLEMENTOPRODUTO b , ITEMFORCAD c
WHERE a.codpro = b.codpro AND a.codpro = c.codpro AND c.quantrec ='0.000' and

    a.codpro ='04609'
```

---

precisa que funcionasse com uma lista:

- a.codpro ='04609'
- a.codpro ='04610'
- a.codpro ='04611' e assim por diante...

Comment: Tentou utilizar a conjunção `OR` em sua cláusula WHERE? Dependendo da quantidade de valores talvez `IN` lhe seja útil.

Comment: O resultado não coincide  com os dados: verifique coluna [filial ped] no resultado.

Comment: E como se faz a junção entre as tabelas A e C? Utilizar somente a coluna `codpro` não garante o resultado.

Comment: somente com o  a.codpro ='04609' funciona certinho, porem preciso inserir mais

 a.codpro ='04609'
 a.codpro ='04610'
 a.codpro ='04611'

Answer (score 0):

A script retorna apenas o valor codpro (4609) pois está especificado no final da clausula WHERE que ela deve fazer isso.
Tente remover o ***and a.codpro ='04609'*** e veja se o resultado é o esperado.

```
SELECT a.filial, a.codpro, b.descricaolonga , 
a.quant, a.estminimo, c.filial AS 'filial ped', 
c.quant AS 'carteira', c.quantrec AS 'recebido'
FROM ITEMFILEST a, COMPLEMENTOPRODUTO b , ITEMFORCAD c
WHERE a.codpro = b.codpro AND a.codpro = c.codpro AND c.quantrec ='0.000'
```

Pela forma como a select foi escrita, acredito que tu seja iniciante. Por isso recomendo o estudo de [junções](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006) e [agrupamentos](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), serão muito úteis a você.

Comment: Sim, sou iniciante. Eu preciso de uma lista de codigos alem desse 4609. Preciso acrescentar mais. Se eu simplesmente remover, vai mostrar todos os itens cadastrados

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso traga o retorno esperado:

```
SELECT a.filial, a.codpro, b.descricaolonga , a.quant, a.estminimo, c.filial AS 'filial ped', c.quant AS 'carteira', c.quantrec AS 'recebido'
FROM ITEMFILEST a
INNER JOIN COMPLEMENTOPRODUTO as b on a.codpro = b.codpro
INNER JOIN ITEMFORCAD  as c on a.codpro = c.codpro
WHERE c.quantrec ='0.000'
```

Comment: Vittoria, sua resposta parece ter funcinado!! Porém ficou faltando o "c.quant AS 'carteira'". Onde incluo ele? Desde já agradeço muito!

Comment: oi,você coloca nas linhas do select que são as tuas colunas
`SELECT a.filial, a.codpro, b.descricaolonga , a.quant, a.estminimo, c.filial AS 'filial ped', c.quant AS 'carteira', c.quantrec AS 'recebido'´ e depois vai o resto

Comment: editei para ficar melhor o entendimento

Comment: Muito obrigado Vittoria, resolveu meu problema :)